# How to extract the digits from a word

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I have a output of the command `df` and using `cut` I have successfully extracted  `22%`. But the problem is I want only `22` not the `%`, as I will be comparing the value with another integer variable. How to do it in Bash ?

Comment: Instead of `cut`-ing out the percentage, you could use

`df --output=pcent /`
That still requires getting rid of the `%`, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and fastest is probably to use bash' [parameter expansion features](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), like this:

```
string="22%"
percentage="${string%\%}"

echo "$percentage"   # Output: 22
```

In `${string%\%}`, the first `%` has the special meaning: *remove from the end of the parameter* (the parameter is `string` in this case).

The second `%` is *what* to remove from the parameter. But since the `%` has a special meaning in this context, it has to be escaped by a `\`.

For more examples and information see the [advanced bash scripting guide chapter 10](http://file:///home/heiko/doc/abs-guide.html#MANIPULATINGVARS).

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways on the command line to extract numbers such as linked to the `sed` or `awk` tools that are POSIX.
However since you inquire directly how to accomplish that with bash. Let us assume we have the a shell variable $VARIABLE which was set to 22% then this code would help you to get only the number `22`

```
user@box:~$ VARIABLE='22%'
user@box:~$ echo "${VARIABLE%%\%}"
```

ouputs 22

Consider that that somewhat confusingly especially with your example the `%` character is used here with a special meaning, such as "substitute from the end of the string stored in the sheel variable". To indicate that what should be removed from the end would be the `%` character literally we have to escape it like this `\%`